# AJAX function inside $.extend not working in jQuery 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, jquery-3

I need to extends jQuery (as a plugin). Problem is, `$.ajax` is not working inside the `$.extend` scope but outside the scope it is working fine. I am using `jQuery 3.4.1` in my project.

**My code:**

```js
(function($) {
  jQuery.extend({
    mmw: function(options) {

      var settings = $.extend({
        mtarget: "#cnapp-mmw",
        imgSize: "square",
        imgRestricted: true,
        imgtype: ["gif", "png", "jpg", "jpeg", "pdf"]
      }, options);

      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://example.com/public/get-media",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
          alert(data);
        },
        error: function(e) {
          alert(e); // Showing this as outout [object Object]
        }
      });
    }
  })
})
```

**But this is showing the proper output:**

```js
(function($) {

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://example.com/public/get-media",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data); // This is showing the proper output
    },
    error: function(e) {
      alert(e);
    }
  });

  jQuery.extend({
    mmw: function(options) {

      var settings = $.extend({
        mtarget: "#cnapp-mmw",
        imgSize: "square",
        imgRestricted: true,
        imgtype: ["gif", "png", "jpg", "jpeg", "pdf"]
      }, options);
    }
  })
})
```

What is wrong in my first code? Is there anything different in jQuery 3?

Please note, I need to call this plugin without selector like

```js
    $(".trigger").on('click', function(){
        $.mmw();
    });
```

Is the `$.extend` is a must required function to do so? Any advice on the best practice for this would be gratefully received.

---

**UPDATE**

After debugging many times I have found that, the AJAX request is not working inside any block or event. I am using this with `Codeigniter 4 (beta 4)`.

**This is showing error**

```js
    $(".trigger").on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://example.com/public/get-media",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data){ alert("Ok"); },
            error: function(e){ alert(JSON.stringify(e)); } // Showing error message {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined"}
        });
    });
```

**But this showing the correct data**

```js
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "<?=base_url('test/'.session_id())?>",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data){ alert(data); }, // Showing the Data
        error: function(e){ alert(JSON.stringify(e)); }
    });

    $(".trigger").on('click', function(){

    });
```

Means Ajax function is only working outside the scope. Really confused about it.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Since the AJAX call is in the `mmw` function, it won't be called until you use `$.mmw()`.

Comment: @Barmar, please take a look at the **last snippet** of my code. After calling the plugin on click event, it is showing the error `alert(e);` which I have commented out in my first snippet.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Use the Network tab to see how the AJAX request is being made, and what the response is.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why it would work differently in the two cases.

Comment: You don't have to use `$.extend`, you can do `$.mmw = function() { ... }`. But the two snippets are very different. The first one makes the AJAX call after the click, the second one makes the AJAX call only when the page is first loaded.

Comment: There's nothing special about `jQuery.extend()`. It's just an ordinary function, it has no effect on variable scope. All it does is merge objects.

Comment: @Barmar, no error in the console. Second snippet is just a part of debugging the issue showing there is no problem in the backend. But if I move the code inside $.extend then the error occurs.

Comment: @Barmar After using `alert(JSON.stringify(e));` I have found this: `{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined"}`

Comment: I suspect something else in your code is breaking `$.ajax`. The reason it works outside the `mmw` function is because that's running before the offending code runs.

Comment: Hanging with this from last 2 days, This code is working fine if I write it as simple JS code (non-plugin style) but not working as a plugin. BTW, thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I am working with CI 4 (beta 4), there was a conflict between above code and the Javascript that has been used by CI 4 for debugging tools. The error is only generated in "development" environment. In "production" environment, everything on working fine.